# Idiomatic Python way of naming a method that converts the object to another format

Tags: python, idioms

I'm looking for what is the most idiomatic way of naming a method that for instance converts the data of a class to xml.

If I were doing this in Ruby I would make a method named `to_xml` for instance, but I've seen several different ways of doing this in Python. `toxml`, `to_xml`, `xml` and `toXML`, for different outputs than XML, but just extrapolating what it would look like for XML. 
And taken how you convert objects for native Python objects (`str()` etc) I don't really know what would be the idiomatic way.

Personally I would just continue and use `to_xml` since that's what I'm used to, but would that be unexpected to an experienced Python programmer?

Comment: I gave the correct answer to the first answer.

Comment: And I gave an upvote to your nice comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) recommends `to_xml`:

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Answer (score 3):

If you go through the [Python Style Guide - PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it is recommended to use all letters in lowercase, with an underscore separating each word.